# PHP で「No input file specified.」

Tags: php, iis

どの時期からかわからないのですが、今まで使えていた PHP on FastCGI for IIS 10 で標記エラーが出るようになりました。よくあるセキュリティ関連も調査しましたが問題なく、上位フォルダからセキュリティを一括上書きも効果ありませんでした。ディスクチェックも済です。
PHP は 5.3 / 5.6 も試しましたが、error_log が書かれないため、なんとなくですが処理が PHP まで届いていない気がします。

また、同じ上位フォルダから新しいフォルダを作成し、そこに PHP を置いたら問題なく動いたため、今は業務上の問題は無くなりましたが、問題のあるフォルダは気になるので調査用として残してあります。他に何か調査できるものはありませんでしょうか?

Comment: `error_log`だけでなくIISやFastCGIのログについても記載してください。

Comment: IISログは以下のとおり。404 が記述されています。
「2018-02-14 03:36:49 127.0.0.1 GET / - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(～省略) - 404 0 0 1103」
FastCGI のログは fastcgi.logging=1 にはなっていますが、どこに書かれるのか結局わかりませんでした。未だに探しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらですが、別の不具合で再インストールすることになったときにわかりましたが、
ハードリンクが設定されており、参照先のリンクが見えなくなったのが原因で
参照できていなかったようです。

以降の調査ができなくなってしまったので、こちらはクローズします。